# Django Rest Framework, use `pk` instead of `id` by default with

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a model as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

And a serializer defined as follows:

```
from . import models

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

`FooSerializer(foo).data` will be dict that has a `id` key, how can one make it have a `pk` key instead of `id` so that it matches the rest of my codebase (that use `pk`, since one-to-one models don't have an id field because they use a FK PK as their own PK.

Answer (score 1):

Customize the serializer to allow a pk field instead of id taking in consideration that the serilaized data source is the model.id

```
from . import models

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = ('pk', ....) # pk plus other fields
```

Comment: Thanks that will work, but not ideal to specify all the other fields manually each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, extending the answer of @misraX .

```
from . import models

class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['pk']
```